# Customise Office 2013 elements in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office, installer, microsoft-office-2013

When I was on Windows 7 to customise elements that are installed with Office 2010 / 2013 I had to:

- open "Add/Remove programs", find correct item and hit "Modify" button or
- run installation program again

and change components list.

Now, I'm forced to use Windows 10 and I'm a little bit lost, because:

- when I hit "Modify" I can only see "Repair" and "Repair Online" and no components list,
- when I run installation program again, it installs Office again and again shows no elements list.

What am I missing? I don't want to *reinstall* or *repair* my Office 2013, because it is fine. I just want to *customise* list of installed elements (actually get rid of one of the components).

How to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a "Repair Online" option, it seems that you are using click-to-run version of Office 2013.

The "Add/Remove programs" option is available in volume licensed MSI Office version. For **click-to-run** Office end-user, there is no option to add/remove apps for specific Office program.

If you are using Office 365 ProPlus, maybe you can consider to use [Office Deployment Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/overview-of-the-office-2016-deployment-tool) to customize the configuration.xml file before Office deployment. The **[ExcludeApp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/configuration-options-for-the-office-2016-deployment-tool#excludeapp-element)** element can help you to block one specific app installation.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I am not 100% sure, if I'm not using click-to-run version (is there a way to check this?), but assuming that I installed it by executing regular setup program found on original DVD / ISO image, I assume that this is original, full-featured version of Office 2013. I'm not using (and cannot use) Office 365 (any version), because usage of it is prohibited in my company.

Comment: To check if you are using click-to-run version of Office, you can open Word 2013, go to File > Account, under Product Information, confirm if there is an Update Options. If there is, it indicates that you are using click-to-run version.

Comment: Thank you. Confirmed. This is a click-to-run version, unfortunately. This, it seems that I'm unable to get rid of anything. Sad, but Microsoft. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to customise elements of Office 2013 under Windows 10, that I found so far, yet a little bit weird, was to install some missing language pack (Polish in my case).

On contrary to "regular" Office's installer, this language pack's installer offered me a normal "Install now" / "Customise" set of buttons and selecting the second one I managed to uninstall every Office 2013 component that I wanted to get rid off.

Solution as weird as Microsoft itself, but at least works fine.

Comment: As you can see from Winnil's answer above answer will work only for full-featured version of Microsoft Office. If you have a click-to-run version you're not able to uninstall anything and changes described in my own answer above are most likely ignored / fake.